# Racket - Produce a new list based on given list

Tags: racket

I'm trying to create a new list based on an original list where each element of the list contains the first element from the original list and second element being the product of the second and third element from the original list.

Example: If the original list is

```
(list (list "A" 2 3) (list "B" 3 4)
```

Then the result will be

```
(list (list "A" 6) (list "B" 12))
```

So far I've written:

```
(define (total-price-list lol)
  (cond
    [(empty? lol) empty]
    [else (list (price-list (first lol))
                (price-list (rest lol)))]))

(define (price-list row)
  (list (first row) (* (second row) (third row))))
```

I don't know how to achieve the wanted result. Can someone help me with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The lambda within the map keeps the first element as is and multiplies the second and the third element of each sublist.

```
(define (total-price-list lol)
  (map (λ (l) (list (first l) (* (second l) (third l)))) lol))

(total-price-list (list (list "A" 2 3) (list "B" 3 4)))
; => '(("A" 6) ("B" 12))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I see what you're saying. However I'm not allowed to use map :(

Comment: We can just lift the lambda into a helper and substitute lol and f into the definition of map: 

`(define (total-price-list lol) (cond [(empty? lol) '()] [else (cons (f (first lol)) (total-price-list (rest lol)))]))`

`(define (f l) (list (first l) (* (second l) (third l))))`

`(total-price-list (list (list "A" 2 3) (list "B" 3 4))) ; => '(("A" 6) ("B" 12))`

(Sorry, SO doesn't allow you to format multi-line code properly in comments)